# Updating a list in json file and keeping the same indent using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm currently making a level editor for a game I made using Pygame. I save the world data in a json file, which contains the different blocks for each column in every row. Trough my level editor, I update the json file and it works, but the indent is messed up so it's unreadable for humans. The data for every level consists out of one list containing many other lists and the line is split after every list. Thanks for helping me!

Before dumping (the way I want it to look after updating)

```
{
  "level_1_data": [
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
      ],

  "level_2_data": [
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
      ]

}
```

After dumping:

```
{
    "level_1_data": [
        [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            8,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            5,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            5,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            4,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            3,
            0,
            0,
            3,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            7,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            0,
            2,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            6,
            6,
            6,
            6,
            6,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ]
    ],
    "level_2_data": [
        [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1
        ],
        [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1,
            1
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
 with open("./world_data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    new_data = data[world.level_name] #Loading level_1_data or level_2_data
    new_data[button[1][3][1]][button[1][3][0]] = 0  #Finding the right index in the 2 layered list
    data[world.level_name] = new_data
    data.update(data)
 with open("./world_data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: @nobleknight that is what OP is doing

Comment: umm, Are you by chance using VS Code as you editor, if so, you might need to turn off all extensions, I copied your json to my sys and tried to save and it automatically formatted is like yours (the way you dont want it).

Comment: @nobleknight The difference is in what they do, not the way they format the output. I've tried it, the result is the same

Comment: @mikeg I am actually using PyCharm but because of you I switched to VS Code and for some reason it actually works in VS Code and the json is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pprint, it will get you alot closer to what you want.

```
import pprint
    
with open("world_data.json", "w") as f:
    pprint.pprint(data, stream = f)
```